# How to maintain API Keys between service instances?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, load-balancing, api-key

I'm creating a WCF service that will make use of a third-party service that requires us to pass a couple of API Keys with a request.  One of the keys must be renewed every 30 days, and the other must be renewed every 24 hours.  These result in a new key being issued.  Since I'll be running multiple load-balanced instances of this service, I need some way to keep the keys renewed and synchronized between those instances.  I'd prefer to renew them well in advance of their expiration time (at least a couple hours before, anyway).

I've looked for solutions to this problem, but aside from finding some row-locking discussions that didn't really result in a resolution to the problem, I haven't found much that addresses the issues.  I may just not be using the correct search terms though.

I have a couple of ideas, but they have downsides, and I'm wondering if there's some better way or even a pattern (or combination of patterns) that I'm unaware of that would provide a better solution.

One issue is how and when to renew the keys.  The renewal process is straightforward, and since I will store the datetime that the key was originally retrieved, I will know when it needs to be renewed.  I could have the service attempt to renew it at a certain time each day if needed, but then all service instances would be attempting to do that at the same time.  I could configure them to try at different times, but then I'd have to ensure that the configs are always set up with different times.  I could see that becoming an issue at some point if they deploy an update and put the same config out for all of them.

I've considered having each web service register itself in the database, and have one of them serve as master service.  Then when the update time rolls around, only the one designated as master would attempt to renew, and it could call a method on the other registered instances to synchronize them after the key has been updated.  I'm thinking I would need to have each service update its status in the database fairly frequently.  They would also need to check the master service to ensure that it has updated recently as well, otherwise another instance would need to take over that role.  This seems like it could get messy, and I don't currently know how a service instance could know whether the server it is running on is currently in the rotation or not.  There would be a lot of scenarios to cover if I do it this way, so I'm not eager to attempt something like this if there is a better way.

So, this seems like something that has probably been solved numerous times, but I'm just not finding the right answers.  I'm sure I could put something together that would get it done, but I'd like to make sure I'm not making things more difficult than they should be, or creating any unnecessary maintenance problems for us.  Any advice on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a cache expiration problem, you need to cache your keys for a finite amount of time then go and refresh the values once the keys in the cache have expired. While you are getting new keys you need to lock the value so that only one service at a time will get the new keys. How you do this will depend on when sort of technologies you are using for storage and caching.

Alternatively you could use a message queue to start the key refresh process, each service could then add a message to the queue when the keys need refreshing, when the queue is processed you can check the key expiry time and only refresh if needed. This has the advantage of offloading the job of getting new keys into an background process rather than relying on your services to do this work for you but you will need some sort of messaging technology to achieve this.

Comment: We're planning to implement Windows Server AppFabric, but don't have it yet.  We do have Service Bus for Windows Server, so that could fit the bill for the message queue option.  The database is SQL Server 2008.  I was hoping to avoid creating an additional service to handle the key updates, but without a distributed cache option right now, I'm not sure if it can be avoided.  I may have to do some experimentation with the locking hints in SQL Server, since I haven't found a good solution for that, and have seen various different methods proposed, most of which were reported to be unsuccessful.

Comment: I think that another issue I have with the caching solution is that, while in many cases, it would be fine if two instances of the service checked the cache at the same time and found that the API key wasn't there (had been expired by the cache), and then both went to a database for it and updated the cache, that wouldn't be a good thing in my situation.  By making that request for a new key to the 3rd party service, they would be changing the key and one of them could end up making a call to that 3rd party service with an invalid key.